# NodeJS: read XLS file from response and convert into json?

Tags: node.js

My nodejs sends request to external service and receives XLS file as response.
I need to parse XLS to json. However, the libraries I found can only parse XLS from filesystem.

Do you know any workaround?

Comment: Did you find a way?

Comment: Sorry I do not remember anymore, most probably not. I switched the company and do not have access to sources to check :(